# How to check if script is bicameral?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, alphabet

Is there a way to check if a script is bicameral, or with two sets of symbols (like upper- and lower-case) for each letter in C#? An example of a bicameral script is Roman and Greek.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for here. What is you *input*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: say my input is a unicode character, is there a function in C# that could tell me what script it is and if that script is bicameral?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no scripts in .Net BCL (or in the Unicode standard either). You can check if a specific character is its own uppercase/lowercase version in a specific `TextInfo` (but beware of edge cases like the German eszett), but they aren't grouped into scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait until tomorrow if there are other responses.

Comment: According to wikipedia, there is an uppercase counterpart to eszett https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E. Is that form accepted nowadays?